# How to change height of view in tableview header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a **tableView header**. I put a view and several items in. However, when a button is tapped, some objects in the view are hidden so that the view doesn't contain it as well anymore:
[image]

[image]

How would I change the **view height** to match the items in the view?

Answer (score 1):

Implementing this delegate function  can help you...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return Your_View.frame.height Or Others
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dynamically sizing the headerview by overriding viewDidLayoutSubviews() and see if that works :)

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Dynamic sizing for the header view
    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        // If we don't have this check, viewDidLayoutSubviews() will get
        // repeatedly, causing the app to hang.
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `sectionHeaderHeight` property in `viewDidLoad`. You will need to have `tableView` reference if you are using storyboard unless if your `ViewCOntroller` is of type `TableViewController` then just use below code.

```
 # Set the Header height to 50 points
 tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50
```